# MATLAB - Plot multiple surface fits in one figure

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, 3d, surface

I have 3 sets of 3D co-ordinates and I have fitted planes to each set. Now, I want to plot all the data points and the 3 planes in one figure.

So far, I have the following function:

```
function [fitresult, gof] = create_fit(xx, yy, zz, grp)

[xData, yData, zData] = prepareSurfaceData( xx, yy, zz );

ft = fittype( 'poly11' );
opts = fitoptions( ft );
opts.Lower = [-Inf -Inf -Inf];
opts.Upper = [Inf Inf Inf];

hold on;
% figure( 'Name', 'fit1' );
[fitresult, gof] = fit( [xData, yData], zData, ft, opts );
h = plot( fitresult, [xData, yData], zData);
if grp == 1
    colormap(hot);
elseif grp == 2
    colormap(cool);
else
    colormap(grey);
end

legend( h, 'fit1', 'zz vs. xx, yy', 'Location', 'NorthEast' );

xlabel( 'xx' );
ylabel( 'yy' );
zlabel( 'zz' );
grid on
```

However, there are 2 problems with this:

1. The planes, when plotted individually are scaled according to the data points which are also plotted with them. When the planes are plotted together, they scale badly and the data points are converge to a small blob (very small scale compared to the planes)
   [image: the points have converged to a small area, but maintain their shape when zoomed in]
   I tried fixing the problem with `axis([-0.04 0.04 -0.04 0.04 -0.04 0.04 -1 1]);`, but it is hard coded and still looks a little off.
   [image: after axis command]
2. The `colormap` command seems to work only when called for the first time. Hence, all the planes turn out to be blue. How can I color each plane and the points fitted for that plane differently?
3. Is this the best way to plot multiple planes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Here is an edited version of my initial answer. The output of `plot` is a two-element graphical object, so you have to call separately `h(1)` and `h(2)` to set the properties of the plane and of the data points.

Here is the code for the function:

```
function [fitresult, gof, h] = create_fit(xx, yy, zz, color)

[xData, yData, zData] = prepareSurfaceData( xx, yy, zz );

ft = fittype( 'poly11' );
opts = fitoptions( ft );
opts.Lower = [-Inf -Inf -Inf];
opts.Upper = [Inf Inf Inf];

hold on;
[fitresult, gof] = fit( [xData, yData], zData, ft, opts );

h = plot( fitresult, [xData, yData], zData);

set(h(1), 'FaceColor', color);
set(h(2), 'MarkerFaceColor', color, 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k');
```

and here is a sample script that calls the function:

```
% Define sample data
N = 20;
x = rand(1,N);
y = rand(1,N);
z = rand(1,N);

% Call the function, specify color
[f1, gof1, h1] = create_fit(x, y, z, 'r');
[f2, gof2, h2] = create_fit(x, y.^10, z, 'g');
[f3, gof3, h3] = create_fit(x.^10, y, z, 'b');

% Figure adjustments
xlabel( 'xx' );
ylabel( 'yy' );
zlabel( 'zz' );
view(3)
grid on

xlim([min(x) max(x)]);
ylim([min(y) max(y)]);
zlim([min(z) max(z)]);
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: The min-max trick worked. However, I get the following error for 'FaceColor': `Argument 'FaceColor' did not match any valid parameter of the parser.`

Comment: Also, is there a way in which each set of points is of different color? This would help in visualizing how well the fitting has worked and also spotting outliers.

Comment: ok, sorry, but as we don't have all the infos you have (values of `xx`, `grp`, ...) I cannot really test my answers. What about replacing `'Facecolor'` with `'color'` ?

Comment: `xx, yy, zz` are just 1D arrays of doubles of the same length. `grp` can be 1, 2 or 3, depending on the plane. Trying 'color' or 'Color' gave the same errors. :/