# Change the color of a surface plot from SFIT in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, polynomials

I have four SFIT object that i plot with:

```
figure;
hold on;
plot(f1);
plot(f2);
plot(f3);
plot(f4);
```

This plots a 3D-Surface.
However I would like to give each surface one unique color, like it is common with the plot function. Usually this is done by giving the paramter 'r' or something that indicates the color, like:

```
plot(f1,'r');
```

However, If I do this here i get the following error:

> Error using plot No value was given for 'r'. Name-value pair arguments
>   require a name followed by a value.
>
> Error in sfit/plot>iParseInputs (line 231) p.parse(
>   parameterValuePairs{:} );
>
> Error in sfit/plot (line 44) [XY, Z, in, out, style, level, hParent] =
>   iParseInputs( obj, varargin{:} );

This indicates that there must be a String to give, but which one ? I already tried something like 'Color' or 'LineColor' but these were not recognized

Simplifaction of the question: I want the planes that represent the fitted object to have one color. And each plane shall have a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this link:

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/153208-how-can-i-make-the-contour-plot-of-an-sfit-object-resemble-the-plot-generated-by-the-contour-com

You could try

```
f1 = fit([x y], z, 'poly23');
ph = plot(f1, 'Style', 'Contour');
set(ph, 'Fill', 'off', 'LineColor', 'auto');
```

Documentation for `set`

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html

---

**Edit**

The above suggestion only displays a 2D plot, see this previous SO answer for the 3D case:

[MATLAB - Plot multiple surface fits in one figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792047/matlab-plot-multiple-surface-fits-in-one-figure)

The relevant code for you is:

```
figure; 
h = plot(f1); 
set(h(1),'FaceColor','r');
```

So the "magic word" which you were looking for is `'FaceColor'`, used in combination with `set` (mentioned above).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however this is not exactly what I wanted. Firstly using plot(f1, 'Style', 'Contour'), leads only to a 2D Plot, where I have a 3D-Plot. When simply using plot(f1) - so that the plot is still 3D the function call for set will give the error: "There is no Fill property on the Surface class"

Comment: Thank you, this link is a litle bit of an overkill but I found the correct line, so simply : figure; h = plot(f1); set(h(1),'FaceColor','r') . I am not sure if this question is a duplicate or not. However, if you could insert that code snippet in your answer I will accept it .

Comment: @Kev1n91 I don't think it's duplicate since you had a simpler request so for a quick reference it's easier to see this solution. I've made the edit, thanks.